# Would there be a problem running a whole house water filter in line like this?

Tags: plumbing, pex, copper, filter

I am in the process of changing the 50 year old copper plumbing in my house to PEX. I wanted to install a filter and scale inhibition system in line right after the valve and meter coming in from outside. Would there be any issues doing it this way? I will include a picture with a crude drawing of what I am proposing.

[image: x]

Comment: I'm not a plumbing expert, so just making these as comments rather than answers.  1. Make sure you have a way to bypass the filter system in case repairs to it are needed and you still need water in the house during repairs.  2. Make sure to jumper that ground wire past your new filter system, so your electrical ground is always continuous through the water piping, in case any of your filter housings are non-metallic.

Comment: Great points, thank you for the input. I didn't think about adding a bypass valve but I will incorporate that into my plan now.

Comment: I don't know if you have a pressure reducing valve (PRV), I don't see one in the pic, but you may have to install it after that valve so that pressure on the filtration system won't be excessive. Check with the manufacturer re water pressure range.

Comment: I would also add another main shutoff valve after the meter. Mine was like yours but after about 40 years it would not shut off completely.

Comment: What size is your incoming water service?

Comment: The incoming pipe is 3/4"